# Magento Bundle Product - challenging task

Tags: magento, bundle

Here is what I need to create.

User selects the gift basket he/she wants to send as a gift. Then, system asks the user to add up to x number of bottles of wine that he/she wants. Then, system asks user to add up to 1kg of nuts  or chocolate etc..

In other words, the user will create his own gift basket adding whatever they want in ordet to send it as a gift.

It seems like I should use the bundle product option. Right? Can anybody give me some direction to that issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to look at bundle products in your situation. You can add different Bundle options for you product (Add New options) and specify their look (drop-down, radio buttons, multi select or check box) and add set of simple products for each option.

Here is a link to guide on how to create a Bundle product for Magento Go (it's almost the same for Magento Community and Enterprise) http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-a-bundled-product

Limitations of bundle products: you cannot add simple products that have any required custom data; configurable products or bundle of bundled products, but there are extensions on the market for that purpose.

Also in your situation (if you want to add up to x number of bottles of wine" etc.)), perhaps it'd be necessary to make your own validation Javascript.

Thanks